# C# Linq DefaultIfEmpty LeftJoin

Tags: c#, linq, left-join, defaultifempty

Some Agents has null in Group field.
I'm trying to do LeftJoin, but receive result like InnerJoin (only Agents with not null Group)

```
Agents = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>((await _repository.GetAgentsAsync() ?? new Agent[] { })
            .Join(Groups.DefaultIfEmpty(), a => a.Group, g => g.ID, (a, g) =>
            new { ID = a.ID, AgentName = a.AgentName, Login = a.Login, AgentID = a.AgentID, IsDel = a.IsDel, Group = g == null ? "Empty" : $"{g.NameGroup} ({g.Num})" }));
```

what the trouble is?

Thanks all, I found answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21584913/13618303

```
        Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>(await _repository.GetGroupsAsync() ?? new Group[] { });
        Agents = new ObservableCollection<Agent>(await _repository.GetAgentsAsync() ?? new Agent[] { });
        AgentsGroups = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>(Agents.GroupJoin(Groups, a => a.Group, g => g.ID, (a, g) => new { Agent = a, Group = g})
            .SelectMany(ag => ag.Group.DefaultIfEmpty(), (a,g) => new { Agent = a.Agent, Group = g })
            .Select ( ag => new { ID = ag.Agent.ID, AgentName = ag.Agent.AgentName, Login = ag.Agent.Login, AgentID = ag.Agent.AgentID, IsDel = ag.Agent.IsDel, Group = ag.Group == null ? "Empty" : $"{ag.Group.NameGroup} ({ag.Group.Num})" }));
```

Comment: Are you saying that Groups will be empty, oare yyou saying that e.g. there will be 100 unique records in Agents and only 80 unique records in Groups ? (So 20 Agents have no Group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method syntax doesn't use `Join` to perform a left join style link, it uses `GroupJoin`. If you straight `Join` then the lack of an element on the right (Group) will mean that the element on the left (Agent) disappears.

A GroupJoin pairs elements on the left with multiple matching elements on the right

```
Left
1, John
2, Mary
3, Joe

Right
1, The Street, 1996
1, The Avenue, 2002
2, The Road, 2010
```

John lived in two places, mary lived in one. Joe never lived anywhere. `Left.GroupJoin(Right)` produces:

```
{1, John}, [ {1, The Street, 1996}, {1, The Avenue, 2002} ]
{2, Mary}, [ {1, The Road, 2010} ]
{3, Joe},  [ ]
```

`GroupJoin` will keep the element on the left and make the element on the right an empty sequence if there is no match

If you needed this back out as a list with repeating elements, you'd SelectMany it, which expands the list-of-lists that the person:addresses represents. I'll come back to this.

---

DefaultIfEmpty does not enable left join behavior; it is just a convenience that returns a sequence containing one item of the target type (and with the default value for the type), if the sequence it is called on has zero elements. In essence it's like:

```
public int[] DefaultIfEmpty(int[] input){
  if(input.Length == 0)
    return new int[1]; //a single integer, value 0 --> the default for int
  else
    return input;
}
```

You don't need it on Groups; it'd be a non op anyway, because if there are 0 Groups, converting it to a list of a single `null` Group will behave the same (no agent will match)

You *do* want `DefaultIfEmpty` if you plan on using SelectMany on your grouping, because SelectMany will not operate at all on a collection of 0 elements. Because Joe had no addresses, SelectMany would skip over him and he would be lost from the output

---

All in, this means you should execute a `GroupJoin`, and you don't really need a `DefaultIfEmpty` anywhere because you aren't doing a `SelectMany`/you can tolerate there being 0 Groups for an Agent in other ways.

I'll use more full names, because it's unfortunate that you're joining to a class called Group (I guess), and a groupjoin gives you a list of Agents, and each Agent in the list has a list of matching Group:

```
.GroupJoin(Groups, agent => agent.Group, group => group.ID, (agent, groupCollection) =>
    new {  
        agent.ID, 
        agent.AgentName,
        agent.Login,
        agent.AgentID, 
        agent.IsDel, 
        GroupNameAndNum = groupCollection.Select(g => $"{g.NameGroup} ({g.Num})").FirstOrDefault() ?? "Empty" 
    }
);
```

If you *were* using SelectMany (perhaps you have agents that have 2 groups and want them listed separately, with the agent data repeated), it would perhaps look like:

```
.GroupJoin(Groups, agent => agent.Group, group => group.ID, (agent, groupCollection) => new { Agent = agent, OneOrMoreGroups = groupCollection.DefaultIfEmpty() })
.SelectMany(
    agentWithGroupsCollection => agentWithGroupsCollection.OneOrMoreGroups,
    (agentWithGroupsCollection, groupsCollectionItem) =>

    new {  
        agentWithGroupsCollection.ID, 
        agentWithGroupsCollection.AgentName,
        agentWithGroupsCollection.Login,
        agentWithGroupsCollection.AgentID, 
        agentWithGroupsCollection.IsDel, 
        GroupNameAndNum = groupsCollectionItem == null ? "Empty" : $"{groupsCollectionItem.NameGroup} ({groupsCollectionItem.Num})"
    }
);
```